# How to use the data dictionary

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying oracle sql and was trying to find the name of all indexes owned by a user with the names of index keys in each index.

I try to find from user_indexes in system catalogue view and display INDEX_NAME, INDEX_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_POSITION but

Below is what I tried:

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type from user_tab_columns;
```

But its seems insufficient to display all the user_indexes.. what should i do

Comment: Why do you select from `user_tab_columns` when you really want `user_indexes`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry i am new here trying to learn about data dictionary on oracle sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view a simple list of indexes and the columns they are using just use user_ind_columns..

```
SELECT * FROM user_ind_columns
```

hope I could help..

Comment: +1, but I think it's more useful if you `ORDER BY index_name, column_position` so that all the columns for a given index appear together, and in the right order.